# Automatically creating and/or extending JPA tables with Wildfly, EclipseLink and Postgres

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, wildfly

I have experienced a strange matter with a Java EE application running on Wildfly 8.1.0 as the server and Postgres as our database system in combination with EclipseLink as the persistence provider *(the reasons why I want to study the costs of migrating from built-in Hibernate to EclipseLink don't matter here)*.

I was getting used to the Hibernate feature of automatically extending the existing database tables by newly added columns when extending the corresponding Entity classes and it would be charming if EclipseLink was able to do so, too - studying the documentation, EclipseLink provides the property

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
```

which sound good to me, but a short test lead to the disillusioning result that it does not work "out of the box" (see minimal example below). Interestingly, if I simply create the respective table in the database without any columns, the table gets filled and works as I wanted, but neither `create-or-extend-tables` nor `drop-and-create-tables` and even not `create-tables` works - the first two only, if I add the mentioned empty table.

Has anyone encountered a situation like this and possibly found a solution?

Additionally, I learned about a Postgres problem regarding transactions

> PostgreSQL seems to abort the transaction if an error occurs, so accessing the database after a failure may not be possible until after calling rollback. ([EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA/PostgreSQL](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA/PostgreSQL))

and as certain error logs point to problems with transactions, maybe this could be a part of the problem?

### Minimal Example

**`persistence.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="..." transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PostgresDS</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**`Name.java`**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Name {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    @Id
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why drop-and-create-tables would work if an empty table exists if create-tables doesn't, as drop-and-create will first drop the table, then behave exactly like create-tables does.  Can you provide the logs showing what might be going wrong?  https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

Comment: @Chris I set the log-level to "ALL" and received the following: pastebin.com/aKaCPRcH. My suspicion concerning your argument: I suspect EclipseLink to check for table existence rather than creating tables and hoping for the best - and as I suspect EclipseLink to check the existence via SQL queries and the queries fail due to lacking table existence, Postgres shows the behavior mentioned in wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA/PostgreSQL above and requires a rollback EclipseLink does not perform and therefore failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have numerous exceptions in the log, all due to using a JTA datasource and being apart of a transaction. See eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/440610 for details, but DDL doesn't work inside most transactions, so you will need to trigger EclipseLink to load the persistence unit upfront with the "eclipselink.deploy-on-startup"="true" persistence property.

Comment: The forum link has nothing to do with EclipseLink, but the added property does the job perfectly!