# java persistence collection of metamodel types is empty

Tags: eclipselink, persistence.xml, jpa-2.1

While deploying my jpa project to wildfly server i am gettings following warning:

```
The collection of metamodel types is empty. 
Model classes may not have been found during entity 
search for Java SE and some Java EE container managed persistence units.  
Please verify that your entity classes are referenced in persistence.xml using 
either <class> elements or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element
```

My persistence xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/example</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="metadata"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="JBoss"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/example"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxx"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My Database tables are not created due to this.

Please help me understand this problem. As i am not able to understand the root cause of this.

Comment: I tried this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406502/automatically-creating-and-or-extending-jpa-tables-with-wildfly-eclipselink-and) but no help

Comment: Are you sure your log message is related to your issue?  Have you tried expliceitely listing classes instead of relying on the exclude-unlisted-classes property to allow scanning the classpath for entities?   You are also specifying a datasource and direct JDBC connection details - only one or the other should be used.  Try setting EclipseLink logging to finest and verify that your classes are being loaded correctly.

Comment: I tried expliceitely listing classes then its working but using exclude-unlisted-classes it is not creating tables

Comment: Entity Classes are not getting recognized by eclipselink. What can be the reason?. Can it be related to Wildfly server or eclipselink version

Answer (score 0):

For people who would come across this question like I did: I've just met this issue in Eclipse 2020-06 when running JPA Tools > Generate Tables from Entities, which is a situation probably different from the one in the question albeit with a strictly identical error message.

It turns out that the only thing needed to work around it is to hit Project > Clean and select the JPA project in the list.
For some unknown reason in my case, cleaning the project is necessary between runs of the Generate Tables command. I can't figure out why but that's the way it is. HTH